# In linear iteration, find values for a,b that cause different outcomes

Tags: dynamical-systems, numerical-linear-algebra

When iterating the equation $X_n=AX_0 + B$ for some initial value $X_0$, I need to find concrete values for $A$ and $B$ that:

1) cause the series to converge for some initial value $X_0$ and diverge for others

and

2) cause the series to converge to different values for different initial values.

Is there a simple way to do this short of trying hundreds of numbers over and over?  Every convergent sequence I create always converges on the same value regardless of the initial value. I've been working on this for a few days and am out of ideas.

Edit: I solved the second part.  For $A=1$ and $B=0$, the series converges to whatever the initial value $X_0$ is.

Comment: For LaTeX/MathJax help on math exchange, you may want to read this: [http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $|A| > 1$ then the series diverges. If $|A|=1$ the series diverges unless $B=0$ in which case it is constant $X_0$ if $A=1$ and flip-flops between $X_0$ and $-X_)$ if $A=-1$.

If, however, $|A| < 1$ we get the interesting phenomenon that the series eventually converges to $\frac{B}{1-A}$. Consider what is happening:
$$
X_0 = X_0\\
X_1 = AX_0 + B \\
X_2 = AX_1 + B = A(AX_0 + B) + B = A^2X_0 + AB + B\\
X_3 = AX_2 + B = A(AX_1 + B) + B = A\left(A\left(AX_0 + B\right) + B\right) + B= A^3X_0 + A^2B + AB +B\\
\ddots\\
X_n = A^nX_0 + B\sum_{k=0}^nA^k\\
$$
We have a geometric series in $A$ being multiplied by $B$. In the limit, $X_0$ disappears since $A < 1$ and we are left with the sum of the infinite geometric series:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}X_n = 0\cdot X_0 + \frac{B}{1-A}
$$

#### Edit

For a specific $X_0^*$, if you pick any $B$ and select $A = 1-\frac{B}{X_0^*}$, that set of $(A,B)$ will converge (constantly) to the initial $X_0^*$ and should diverge for other $X_0$. For example, $X_0 = 2$. Picking $B = 6, A = -2$ will constantly return $2$ but the same factors for $X_0 = 1$ oscillates wildly and diverges. If $|1-\frac{B}{X_0}| < 1$ then the series will converge as above to $X_0$ since $\frac{B}{1-(1-\frac{B}{X_0})}=X_0$

Comment: I understand the series, but what I am seeking is a particular solution for $A$ and $B$ that causes the series to converge for one Initial Value and diverge for others.  For example, a value for $A,B$ that converges if $X_0=1$ but diverges if $X_0=2$.

Comment: Sorry, I read "diverge for others" to mean other $A$ and $B$. See the edit for an answer to what you meant.

Comment: thank you very much.  i apologize for the ambiguity and will be more clear in the future